# Scrollbars Chrome update 121

Tags: css, google-chrome, scrollbar

Chrome just launched update 121 a few days ago and I just noticed the scrollbars on my websites look like this [ugly scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmuTI.png) while they used to look like this [cool scrollbar with rounded corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxaX5.png)

Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: BTW, the whole `::-webkit-scrollbar...` selectors are gone - you should be using (unprefixed) `scrollbar-color` and `scrollbar-width` properties (not selectors), see the article: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-chrome-121

Comment: @Dai No question, just something I noticed and wanted to share a fix about ^^.
Is there something about `::-webkit-scrollbar` being removed on your link ? I didn't see that, but trying to use these new properties will break the old ones (including border-radius, which doesn't have a new property to allow customisation).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no question is being asked. SO is a programming Q&A platform. If you want to keep this, you need to form a question and put an appropriate answer in the Answer section below. SO is NOT a forum.

Comment: @Rob Sorry for the mess. I'm new to posting here, I'll do as you suggested.

Answer (score 8):

Chrome now prefers the new scollbar properties — `scrollbar-color` and `scrollbar-width` over the `-webkit-*` selectors which are used to style scrollbars. I too experienced this after upgrading to chrome 121 and I have documented my case here https://syntackle.com/blog/changes-to-scrollbar-styling-in-chrome-121/. But a quick fix would be to wrap the new properties in a `@supports` rule check for browsers which don't support webkit selectors, example firefox.

```css
/* Wrap new scrollbar properties in @supports rule for browsers without `::-webkit-scrollbar-*` support */
/* This way chrome won't override `::-webkit-scrollbar-*` selectors */
@supports not selector(::-webkit-scrollbar) {
  html {
      scrollbar-width: thin;
      scrollbar-color: var(--thumb-color) var(--track-color);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using SASS you will need to escape the `*::-webkit-scrollbar`. So it would look something like this: `@supports #{'\not selector(*::-webkit-scrollbar)'} {`

Comment: @RickyBoyce this worked for me in `scss`!

```@supports (not selector(::-webkit-scrollbar)) { html { scrollbar-width: thin; scrollbar-color: #6d7c77 #cfd7c7; } }```
it compiled to valid CSS

Comment: Scrollbars changed and I tried to change the -webkit to non-webkit but they still did not change back to the way they were. Any ideas?

Comment: @PetarVasilev you should not remove the `::-webkit` selectors if you are relying on them, instead wrap the non webkit properties in a supports rule check

Comment: tried the @-moz-document url-prefix() and it worked

Answer (score 5):

If you experience this too it might be because you have two ways of styling CSS : one for chrome and one for firefox :

```
/* FIREFOX */
* {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) transparent;
}

/* CHROME */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

To fix it you just have to move your Firefox specific CSS inside a `@-moz-document url-prefix()` bloc like this :

```
/* FIREFOX */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  * {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) transparent;
  }
}
```

The Chrome patchnote [here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-chrome-121?hl=fr) says they added support for scrollbar-color and scrollbar-width but it seems that these properties cancel the old ones. That wouldn't be a problem if there was only color and width, but I had other ones like border-radius that don't seem to get a replacement.

You can try with this snippet in chrome and firefox :

```css
/* FIREFOX */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
* {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) transparent;
  }
}

/* CHROME */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to remove `scrollbar-width: thin` and use `&::-webkit-scrollbar`, `&::-webkit-scrollbar-track` and `&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` to style your scrollbar in Chrome.

Example:

```css
#root {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* REMOVE THIS: */
  /* scrollbar-width: thin; */
  
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border-width: 12px 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #bdbdbd;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id=root>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Both are needed because the scrollbar-width and scrollbar-color are the only ones working on firefox

Answer (score -1):

God, I thought it's only something wrong with my installed version. It's an ugly update. Only happening in windows based machines.
I just removed this : `scrollbar-width: thin;` and all good now

Comment: I had this property to style the scrollbar in Firefox, didn't you lose the Firefox styling by doing that?